# NodeJS + mssql como fazer uma sequencia de buscas

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, sql-server, node.js

Estou iniciando com **nodejs** e me surgiu um problema que já estou a alguns dias resistindo a não postar aqui, mas parece que não tenho conhecimento suficiente e não encontro material ao pesquisar sobre mssql e NodeJS, então vim pedir ajuda aqui.

Eu preciso fazer uma sequencia de consultas no banco de dados, então criei o seguinte codigo:

```
router.post('/importbom', (req, res) => {

    const { listaBom } = req.body;
    let filter = "";

    listaBom.forEach((item, i) => {

        sql.close();
        if (item) {
            const { mpn, descricao } = item;

            filter = "CompName LIKE '0%' " + `AND CompID = '${mpn}' `;
            if (descricao !== null) {
                filter += "OR CompName LIKE '0%' ";
                let arrayWord = descricao.split(" ");
                arrayWord.forEach((word, i) => {
                    if (!i) filter += `AND Remark LIKE '%${word.replace('%', '[%]')}%' `;
                    if (i) filter += `AND Remark LIKE '% ${word.replace('%', '[%]')}%' `;
                });
            }

            sql.connect(vmanagerConfig).then(pool => {
                return pool.request()
                    .query(`SELECT 
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(CompName)) AS ipnProd, 
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(Remark)) AS descricao, 
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(CompID)) AS CompID,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(McID)) AS ID,
                    LTRIM(RTRIM(Amount)) AS amt,
                    ipnCad = 0,
                    mnfpartno as mpn
                    FROM ComponentTrace
                    WHERE ${filter} and McID <> 9999`).then(result => {
                        console.log(result.recordset);

                    });
            }).catch(err => {
                sql.close();
                console.log("--> Erro na linha ..., index.js ", err);
            });

            sql.on('error', err => {
                sql.close();
                console.log("--> Erro na linha ..., index.js: ", err);
            });

        }


    });


    res.send([]); //por hora não estou usando

})
```

ele recebe uma lista e cada linha dessa lista deve ser uma consulta, só que ele passa n vezes pelo for e me retorna apenas um resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) no `sql.connect` e `pool.request().query` indicam que os seus retornos são promessas. Sendo assim o seu código é executado assíncronamente. Para executá-los de forma organizada você pode usar o `async/await` da seguinte forma:

```
const mountFilter = ({ mpn, descricao }) => {
  let filter = `CompName LIKE '0%' AND CompID = '${mpn}' `;

  if (descricao !== null) {
    filter += "OR CompName LIKE '0%' ";
    let arrayWord = descricao.split(" ");
    arrayWord.forEach((word, i) => {
      if (!i) filter += `AND Remark LIKE '%${word.replace('%', '[%]')}%' `;
      if (i) filter += `AND Remark LIKE '% ${word.replace('%', '[%]')}%' `;
    });
  }
  
  return filter;
};

const post = async (req, res) => {
  const { listBom } = req.body;
  const results = [];

  for (let i = 0, tamanho = listaBom.length; i < tamanho; i++) {
    const pool = await (new sql.ConnectionPool(/** configurações da conexão **/)).connect();
    const item = listaBom[id];

    if (item) {
      const filter = mountFilter(item);
      const { recordset: result } = await pool
        .request()
        .query(`SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(CompName)) AS ipnProd, 
                       LTRIM(RTRIM(Remark)) AS descricao, 
                       LTRIM(RTRIM(CompID)) AS CompID,
                       LTRIM(RTRIM(McID)) AS ID,
                       LTRIM(RTRIM(Amount)) AS amt,
                       ipnCad = 0,
                       mnfpartno as mpn
                  FROM ComponentTrace
                 WHERE ${filter} and McID <> 9999`);

      results.push(result);
    }
  };
  
  res.send(results);
};

router.post('/importbom', post);
```

**Observação:** Eu não usaria a `query` da forma que você utilizou. Talvez seja possível melhorar o esquema de filtro.

---

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.

Comment: Utilizei a forma indicada, mas ele fecha a conexão.

Comment: sobre o filtro eu vou melhorar, contudo não dei tanta importância a isso ainda, só queria essa rota funcionando, alis obrigado por tentar ajudar ;)

Comment: @G.Laveli tenta colocar a criação do pool dentro do for

Comment: Desculpe acho que não entendi com fazer isso.

Comment: @G.Laveli alterei no meu exemplo

Comment: const pool = await sql.ConnectionPool(vmanagerConfig);
                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Ele entrou no for e gerou o seguinto log: https://i.imgur.com/sNtYKso.png

Comment: @G.Laveli alterei o foreach para for

Comment: para resolver o problema do const pool = await sql.ConnectionPool(vmanagerConfig); ^^^^^ SyntaxError: await is only valid in async, eu coloqueo o async no for ficando assim:  listaBom.forEach(async (item, i) => {

Comment: @G.Laveli fiz outra alteração no código

Comment: Funcionou ;) Obrigado por ter ajudado.